# Dynamically add data points method for graph C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to add points to a graph dynamically(on load). There will be an unknown amount of values I am pulling from my static list method.

List method:

```
public static List<Class1> getData()
{

    List<Class1> List = new List<Class1>();

    StringBuilder sqlString = new StringBuilder();
    sqlString.Append("SELECT ScaleGroup FROM WorkOrder");

    SqlDataReader reader = null;
    SqlConnection dbConn = DBHelper.getConnection();

    try
    {
        reader = DBHelper.executeQuery(dbConn, sqlString.ToString(), null);
        if (reader != null)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Class1 cd = new Class1();
                cd.ScaleGroup = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ScaleGroup"]);
                List.Add(cd);
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
        reader.Dispose();
        dbConn.Close();
        dbConn.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }

    return List;
}
```

Then I want to set my graph to populate with that list and here is what I have so far:

```
List<Class1> points = Class1.getData();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    chart1.Series.Add(points[i].ToString());
    chart1.DataBind();
}
```

When I run it I get the error: Data points insertion error. Only 1 Y values can be set for this data series. What can I add to my above method to I guess dynamically add those data points?

Comment: What kind of chart are you using? Also, you shouldn't need to databaind in your for loop (should be done afterwards, if you need it at all since it doesn't look like you are using databinding).

Comment: @LordTakkera fair enough used another post for help and line graph.